# How to make a empty field behave like a null field value when it comes to standard values?

Tags: templates

By default, **standard values are only applied to a template field if its value is null**.

I heard during the *Sitecore Developer Foundation* training that we can configure it so that an empty field would be replaced by its default value present in the standard values as well (note that Sitecore handles empty values differently from null values).

I was wondering, how we can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you check the "Reset blank" in the field's definition item, then it will set the standard value [which you entered in the _standard value of that template] whenever you clear/delete the field value.

[image]